# Checking whether user is logged in passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I use passport.js to authenticate user. I have 2 function there to check whether user is logged in or not.
First function:

```
isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

2nd function:

```
isLoggedInCheck(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I take these 2 functions in class called Helper.
When I use the 1st function (I pass it in routes function as middleware) it works:

```
var Helper = require('../helpers/helper');
var helper = new Helper();
router.get('/', helper.isLoggedIn, admin.melihat_daftar_venue);
```

But when i want to use second function:

```
if (helper.isLoggedInCheck) {
//code
}
else{

}
```

The function just return function definition instead of true/false. How to fix it. Thanks

Comment: try `if (helper.isLoggedInCheck(req)) {`

Comment: no  it returns error

Comment: see the detailed answer bellow, what is error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You are using `isLoggedIn` as a ExpressJS middleware while `isLoggedInCheck` inside condition that's why you need to call function( `helper.isLoggedInCheck(req, res)` inside if condition while define inside `get` function

```
if (helper.isLoggedInCheck(req, res)) {
//code
}
else{

}
```

and  first one is

```
router.get('/', helper.isLoggedIn, admin.melihat_daftar_venue);
```

or *(not recommended, just showing example)*

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  helper.isLoggedIn(req, res, next)
}, admin.melihat_daftar_venue);
```

Comment: but req and res must be initialize before pass it inside isLoggedInCheck. How to initialize httpreq(req) and response here? @Arif Khan